# How to fill python dictionary while creating it

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I'm searching for a way of filling a python dictionary at the same time it is created

I have this simple method that firstly creates a dictionary with all the keys at value 0 and then it reads the string again to fill it

```
def letter_count(word):
    letter_dic = {}
    for w in word:
        letter_dic[w] = 0
    for w in word:
        letter_dic[w] += 1
    return letter_dic
```

The method above should count all the occurrences of each letter in a given string

Input:

```
"leumooeeyzwwmmirbmf"
```

Output:

```
{'l': 1, 'e': 3, 'u': 1, 'm': 4, 'o': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 1, 'w': 2, 'i': 1, 'r': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1}
```

Is there a form of creating and filling the dictionary at the same time without using two loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is!
The most pythonic way would be to use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

letter_dic = Counter(word)
```

But there are other options, like with pure python:

```
for w in word:
    if w not in letter_dic: 
        letter_dic[w] = 0
    letter_dic[w] += 1
```

Or with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). You pass one callable there and on first key access it will create the key with specific value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

letter_dic = defaultdict(int)
for w in word:
   letter_dic[w] += 1
```

Comment: The last one is the pythonic way (should probably be moved as first answer)

Comment: For the second one, an alternative to the test could be `letter_dic[w] = letter_dic.get(w, 0) + 1` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehension, e.g.

```
x = "leumooeeyzwwmmirbmf"
y = {l: x.count(l) for l in x}
```

Comment: I am crying, this is `O(n^2)` and in human language - very slow and uneffective ;/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from `collections`:

```py
from collections import Counter
src = "leumooeeyzwwmmirbmf"
print(dict(Counter(src))
```

gives expected

```
{'l': 1, 'e': 3, 'u': 1, 'm': 4, 'o': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 1, 'w': 2, 'i': 1, 'r': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1}
```